# Starting Timer with JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I was wondering how I can make a 'timer' start when a JButton is clicked. I have looked around to see if there was answer relevant to my situation and I couldn't find one.

Here is a code example from my previous question:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GreenRects extends JPanel {

    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;

    private static final int OFFSET = 100;
    private static final int SIZE = 20;
    private static final int INC = 5;

    int[] xPoints = new int[5];

    public GreenRects() {
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.length; i++) {
            xPoints[i] = x;
            x += OFFSET;
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.length; i++) {
                    if (xPoints[i] + INC < SCREEN_WIDTH) {
                        xPoints[i] += INC;
                    } else {
                        xPoints[i] = 0;
                    }
                }

                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.length; i++) {
            g.fillRect(xPoints[i], 0, SIZE, SIZE);
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new GreenRects());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be straightforward once you have read up on how to make something happen when a button is clicked. Please try to code it yourself and then get back to us if you have trouble.

Comment: -1 for not even trying. I'm sure you can do better, and will do better in the future.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked the question if I never tried. Irrelevant, but I  made a java calculator.

Comment: OK, I retract my statement but not my vote since you didn't post it. How will we know where you might be messing up if you don't post your attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make `timer` an instance variable...

```
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;

    private static final int OFFSET = 100;
    private static final int SIZE = 20;
    private static final int INC = 5;

    int[] xPoints = new int[5];
    // Add me here...
    private Timer timer;
```

Don't forget to remove the old declaration...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
```

Should become

```
timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
```

Otherwise you will end up with a shadow variable and possible `NullPointerException`.

Next, create a `JButton` and add an `ActionListener` to it and within it, call `timer.start()`

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.start();
    }
});
```

Now, don't forget to add it to your UI so the user can click it...

Take a look at [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

**Updated**

Based on comments, I would add a `start` and maybe even a `stop` method to the `GreenRects` class.  These would call the `timer`....

```
public void start() {
    timer.start();
}
```

From there, when the button's `ActionListener` is triggered, you would simply call `start` method of the instance of `GreenRects`...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    greenRects.start();
}
```

I would then add the button to some other container, so that it didn't interrupt with what the `GreenRects` class is painting...

Comment: I understand that I need to add **timer.start();** within the ActionListener but the main problem I'm having is syntax.

Comment: You'll need to explain that further, cause there's no button in your example code...

Comment: Ok nevermind my earlier comment. Do I have to create a panel for the button or is there an easier way to add the button onto the frame?

Comment: Yes and no.  This depends on how you've add the original panel.  Based on that comment, what I would do is create a method in your `GreenRects` class called `start` (and maybe even `stop`), which simply calls `timer.start()` (or `timer.stop()`). From there, I would call this method from the button you create for your frame.  How you add the button to the frame depends on how you've set things up, but I wouldn't add it to the `GreenRects` panel...

Comment: @JavaDude On top of the above suggestions, what you should do is create a separate JPanel for the painting and then add that Panel to the main panel, along with the button. If you just try to add the button to existing panel, it will overlap the painting. You can create an inner class JPanel that has the `paintComponent` method

Comment: The website was very helpful, thank you very much :D. @MadProgrammer. I got it to work.

Comment: @peeskillet I understand what you're trying to say. I might try to set the location of the button using the default flow layout instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an `ActionListener`, but you give it nothing to listen to.  Fortunately, `JButton`, through its `AbstractButton` superclass, has an `addAction` method.  Create an `Action` instance, usually through its concrete implementation `AbstractAction`, and add it to the button.  The advantage of `Action` over `ActionListener` is that you can add it to `JMenuItem`s too.

Comment: Ahh, the `ActionListener` that I see is attached to the timer?

Comment: Your action listener is attached to the timer, so when the timer buzzes, your action gets performed.  But, your constructor turns on the timer. You don't create a button, so no user action will start the timer.